# Make this dot plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to make the image shown here:

[image: here]

Using R code. Is there something better than dot plot for this type of figure? Basically I want to show the means and variability between two groups for 6 variables. Sample data provided below. Thanks a million!

```
 id var1 var2 var3  var4 group
 1  12    3    22   60    1
 2  8     6    19   55    1
 3  25    30   70   26    2
 4  26    31   75   31    2
 5  22    29   80   29    2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that should get you started

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(variable, v, -id, -group) %>%
    group_by(group, variable) %>%
    summarise(value = mean(v), value.sd = sd(v)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(
        variable = as.factor(variable),
        group = as.factor(group)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = variable, shape = group)) +
        geom_point(size = 4) +
        geom_segment(aes(x = value - value.sd, xend = value + value.sd, yend = variable))
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "id var1 var2 var3  var4 group
 1  12    3    22   60    1
 2  8     6    19   55    1
 3  25    30   70   26    2
 4  26    31   75   31    2
 5  22    29   80   29    2", header = T)
```